# python tkinter interface how to create a new to show txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, tkinter, ttk

I buid a code which takes python user input and insert it into a text file when pressing apply as shown in the picture bellow

[image: GUI]

and the text file will always be updated when the user inserts a new text, how to create an new button next to apply to show up to date text file to the user

[image]
and want prevent to enter the same text 
example if the text file has a (go) the program do not enter (go) again
this is my code

```
root = Tk()

ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0)

ivn2 = StringVar()
inputVarName2 = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn2))
ivn2.set(str("text2"))
inputVarName2.grid(row=1, column=0)




def writetofile():
    content_list = [ivn.get(), ivn2.get()]

    print("\n".join(content_list))    
    with open("help.txt", "a") as f:
        for item in content_list:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=1)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying something same but with one output

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("The Gatway company")

ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)
def writetofile():
    content_list = [ivn.get()]
    if any(content_list):


        with open("help.txt", 'r+') as inFile:
            for item in content_list:
                if ("%s\n" % item).encode('UTF-8') in inFile:
                    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning", "'%s': Already exists!" % item)
                    return

        with open("help.txt", "a") as f:
            for item in content_list:
                f.write( ("%s\n" % item).encode('UTF-8'))

    ivn.set('')

def showfile():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("help.txt")
    textArea = Text(top)

    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(top, command=textArea.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

    textArea['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

    with open("help.txt", "r") as infile:
        textArea.insert(END, infile.read())

    textArea.grid(row=0, column=0)
    textArea.config(state=DISABLED)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E)
applyButton.config( height = 5, width = 10 )

showButton = Button(root, text="Show", command=showfile)
showButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E)
showButton.config( height = 5, width = 10 ) 



root.mainloop()
```

it's same as your code but  for one entry, I'm thinking to edit it in a such way that the user chooses the help.txt file like a file requester.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a user from inserting the same text just empty the two entries, and you can check if entries are not empty before saving to a file.

You can use a top-level window to show the file content.

Check the following example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, Entry, StringVar, Text, DISABLED, END, W, E 
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()


ivn = StringVar()
inputVarName = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn))
ivn.set(str("text1"))
inputVarName.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)

ivn2 = StringVar()
inputVarName2 = Entry(root, textvariable=str(ivn2))
ivn2.set(str("text2"))
inputVarName2.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=2)


def writetofile():
    content_list = [ivn.get(), ivn2.get()]
    if any(content_list):
        print("\n".join(content_list))

        with open("help.txt", 'r+') as inFile:
            for item in content_list:
                if ("%s\n" % item).encode('UTF-8') in inFile:
                    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning", "'%s': Already exists!" % item)
                    return

        with open("help.txt", "a") as f:
            for item in content_list:
                f.write( ("%s\n" % item).encode('UTF-8'))

    ivn.set('')
    ivn2.set('')


def showfile():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("help.txt")
    textArea = Text(top)

    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(top, command=textArea.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

    textArea['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

    with open("help.txt", "r") as infile:
        textArea.insert(END, infile.read())

    textArea.grid(row=0, column=0)
    textArea.config(state=DISABLED)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=writetofile)
applyButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E)

showButton = Button(root, text="Show", command=showfile)
showButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E)



root.mainloop()
```

Edited to answer @IbrahimOzaeri question in comments.
You can use `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` to ask user to select a file:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

root = Tk()
root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203186/discussion-on-answer-by-kenly-python-tkinter-interface-how-to-create-a-new-to-sh).